# Creating a new file each time program runs

Tags: c#

In a for each loop I am currently adding to my file like this:

```
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append(LastName.Trim()).Append("\t");
        // more stuff
```

But every time that user runs the program I want that file to be created from scratch. Currently it is creating the file if it does not exists - which is good - but it is also appending to the end of the previously created file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`TextWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.aspx)

```
// Create file a single time
using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(path)) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        // Add content to the file inside the loop
        writer.Write(LastName.Trim());
        //etc...
    }       
}
```

Comment: Can I still use my StringBuilder and just at the end say writer.Write(builder) ?

Comment: @DevWannaBe: yes, you have to do `writer.Write(builder.ToString())`

Answer (score 3):

You are using [`File.AppendText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - what did you expect?

If you want to override the file on each run, use [`File.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a Tempfile with:

[`Path.GetTempFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx)

and store all filenames in one central file that does not change.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))`

Try `using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("fileName.txt"))`

You are appending instead of creating something new / overwriting what is there.